# MATLAB code for clock generator which depends on the value of L and C

Tags: matlab, simulink, clock

Given the values of L and C. how can i generate a sinusoidal or square wave using MATLAB code?

```
i tried this
l = value;
c = value;
f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(l*c);
```

but it just give a value. which is quite obvious. but i want to get a continuous pulse out of it. because i need to simulate it in SIMULINK. i cant use any inbuilt SIMULINK clock as i want a clock which depends on the values of l & c. is it possible to write a code for this thing?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  You initially ask for MATLAB code (and 2 of the answers give you that), but then say that you're needing to do it in Simulink.  Which one is it?  MATLAB or Simulink?  If Simulink, why can't you just use the Sine Wave block with the frequency set to the appropriate value?

Answer (score 0):

To get a seies of values one option is to turn c and l into arrays:

```
c = [1:5]; l = [1:5];
f = 1./(2*pi*sqrt(l.*c);
```

If c and l need to be calculated each model step then it would be simpler to just draw out in Simulink blocks the calculation of f from the previous instances of c and l (use unit delay blocks to save them from the previous model step).

Answer (score 0):

I guess here you want to generate sine wave with frequency 
f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(l*c)

you can try this code

```
t = [0:1/30000:2]; % you can change duration and sampling period as per your requirement 
Amplitude=value;
l = value;
c = value;
f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(l*c);
y = A*sin(2*pi*f*t);
plot(y);
```

Comment: hi, my frequency is in range of Ghz, so when i use the sampling rate that is twice the operating frequency. then it keeps on running does not generate any wave. is that we can not use Ghz in the matlab function?

Comment: you can definitely use frequency in range of GHz. Try reducing the duration of wave. i.e change value 2 to 0.000002

Comment: i have re wrote the question u can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951081/to-generate-a-clock-using-matlab-in-ghz?noredirect=1#comment55665056_33951081